# RTSP клиент для Андроид

Tags: java, rtsp

Всем привет,подскажите пожалуйста как можно запустить потоковое видео с IP камеры в своем приложении?
Пытался по такой схеме

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
 
    final static String USERNAME = "admin";
    final static String PASSWORD = "";
    final static String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.10:554/mode=real&idc=1&ids=1";
 
    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);
 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        // Configure the view that renders live video.
        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        _mediaPlayer.start();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);
 
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
        Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);
 
        try {
            // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
            _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);
 
            // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
            _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
 
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _mediaPlayer.release();
    }
 
    private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders() {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String basicAuthValue = getBasicAuthValue(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        headers.put("Authorization", basicAuthValue);
        return headers;
    }
 
    private String getBasicAuthValue(String usr, String pwd) {
        String credentials = usr + ":" + pwd;
        int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
        byte[] bytes = credentials.getBytes();
        return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(bytes, flags);
    }
}
```

Но вместо видео - черный экран.Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать?В манифесте доступ к инету есть.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через **libvlc**

```
package com.pedro.vlctestapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.pedro.vlc.VlcListener;
import com.pedro.vlc.VlcVideoLibrary;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer;

/**
 * Created by pedro on 25/06/17.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VlcListener, View.OnClickListener {

  private VlcVideoLibrary vlcVideoLibrary;
  private Button bStartStop;

  private String[] options = new String[]{":fullscreen"};

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    bStartStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_start_stop);
    bStartStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    vlcVideoLibrary = new VlcVideoLibrary(this, this, surfaceView);
    vlcVideoLibrary.setOptions(Arrays.asList(options));
    vlcVideoLibrary.play("rtsp://admin:@192.168.0.58:554/mode=real&idc=1&ids=1");
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onError() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error, make sure your endpoint is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    vlcVideoLibrary.stop();
    bStartStop.setText(getString(R.string.start_player));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBuffering(MediaPlayer.Event event) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!vlcVideoLibrary.isPlaying()) {
      vlcVideoLibrary.play("rtsp://admin:@192.168.0.58:554/mode=real&idc=1&ids=1");
      bStartStop.setText(getString(R.string.stop_player));
    } else {
      vlcVideoLibrary.stop();
      bStartStop.setText(getString(R.string.start_player));
    }
  }
}
```